# SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host - error even after enabling openssl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am getting the following error :(I know its a common issue )

> **SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. (10060) SMTP Error: Could not connect to
>   SMTP host.**

I am using xampp and have enabled:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

my php :

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $message= 'Full Name: '.$_POST['fullname'].'<br />
    Email: '.$_POST['emailid'].'<br />
    Subject: '.$_POST['subject'].'<br />
    Comments: '.$_POST['comments'].'';
    require "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php"; //include phpmailer class

    // Instantiate Class
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Set up SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    $mail->IsSMTP();                // Sets up a SMTP connection
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;         // Connection with the SMTP does require authorization
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';      // Connect using a TLS connection
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  //Gmail SMTP server address
    $mail->Port = 465;  //Gmail SMTP port
    $mail->Encoding = '7bit';

    // Authentication
    $mail->Username   = "xxxxxxx"; // Your full Gmail address
    $mail->Password   = "xxxxxx"; // Your Gmail password

    // Compose
    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['emailid'], $_POST['fullname']);
    $mail->Subject = "New Contact Form Enquiry";      // Subject (which isn't required)
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    // Send To
    $mail->AddAddress("xxxxxxxxxx", "Recipient Name"); // Where to send it - Recipient
    $result = $mail->Send();  // Send!
 $message = $result ? 'Successfully Sent!' : 'Sending Failed!';
 unset($mail);
}
?>
```

note : it works perfect as I load it to a different server.
http://79.170.40.183/maprofile.com/

Comment: Firstly, abit of advice....remove that URL from Stack and your webserver before your associated email address is banned. Secondly, what happens if you telnet from CLI to port 465? Do you get any response? `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`

Comment: @Kitson88 thanks for the input.I get the following error :

Comment: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. (0)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Comment: It looks to me that it's unable to resolve the IP address for `smtp.gmail.com`. I'm unable to confirm because the error message you gave me is not an error from a CLI though. Can you try the above steps mentioned by seeing if your PC can access gmail. If your telnet is successful, you should see the following in Terminal/CLI/CMD Prompt: `Trying 74.125.71.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.`

Comment: @Kitson88 it is saying couldnot open connections to the host on port 465.I tried for 587,80 and 25 also.

Comment: It sounds to me that your external IP address is being blocked by gmail or your ISP is blocking all SMTP ports out (which I highly doubt). Just out of curiosity, what IP address do you get when you ping in terminal e.g. `ping smtp.gmail.com`? You should see the IP address, can you paste it in the comments box. Also firewall on local PC, is that disabled or correct rules set for SMTP (In & Out).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133263/discussion-between-jane-and-kitson88).